# ActionView::Template::Error (ui.jqgrid isn't precompiled) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I'm Running my application using nginx server and passenger,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (ui.jqgrid isn't precompiled):
    21:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "new" %>
    22:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" %>
    23:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "buttons"%>
    24:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "ui.jqgrid"%>
    25:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.multiselect.css"%>
    26:         <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.multiselect.filter.css"%>
```

I have pre-compiled all my assets.I have included following code in my application.rb file

```
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
    if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
        full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
        app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
        if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
          puts "including asset: " + full_path
          true
        else
          puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
          false
        end
    else
        false
    end
    end
```

I `public/assets` can see its compiled version, but still I'm getting message that file is not pre compiled.

```
public/assests/ui.jqgrid-4a84577046aa358c9ee125bf6a1a85de.css
public/assests/ui.jqgrid-4a84577046aa358c9ee125bf6a1a85de.css.gz
public/assests/ui.jqgrid.css
public/assests/ui.jqgrid.css.gz
```

**Update:**
My manifest.yml

```
ui.jqgrid.css: ui.jqgrid-4a84577046aa358c9ee125bf6a1a85de.css
ui.multiselect.css: ui.multiselect-18d6d97e6b62659bfd94b81d54ed7ec0.css
```

On my local machine its works fine, but when I deploy my code on production server(nginx + passenger) its crashing.

Please suggest...

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Yes I have restarted my server

Comment: Why are there these files `ui.jqgrid.css` & `ui.jqgrid.css.gz` in your `public/assets` folder. In your case, I would try to see what the `manifest.yml` contains.

Comment: `ui.jqgrid.css: ui.jqgrid-4a84577046aa358c9ee125bf6a1a85de.css
 ui.multiselect.css: ui.multiselect-18d6d97e6b62659bfd94b81d54ed7ec0.css` This is there in my manifest

Comment: I suggest you clean your public/assets folder and do a precompilation. Your assets folder should not contain these two files without a digest.

Comment: Yes I did that, but contains this files in that.Can you please explain me which two files without digest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are including CSS or JS file, if that file name contains dot then it assume that its a file extension, here it is assuming `jqgrid` as file extension,

So just change `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "ui.jqgrid"%>` To

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "ui.jqgrid.css"%>
```

And it works !!!